# Vuex clear data from heap

Tags: javascript, vue.js, memory, vuejs2, heap-memory

- **Issue** - When i click on one of the listed projects it's routing to project and showing structuresTree data of 168mb, then data become to be 2GB
- When i'm going back to projects my heap stay 2GB, I'm working with large data so when i'm going back to projects i need to clear the JavaScript VM Instance.

what have i tried to clear the JavaScript VM Instance:

```
beforeDestroy() {
    this .$store.commit("structures/setStrItemTree", []);
    this.$store._vm.$destroy();
}
```

and it didn't work and JavaScript VM Instance showing: 2GB

**My code:**

This my state:

```
    state: {
        structuresTree: [],
    },
    mutations: {
        setStrItemTree: (state, structuresTree) => (state.structuresTree = structuresTree),
    },
```

I have 2 routes (Porjects - show all the projects list, Project - show project details and structure)
Inside **project** i have:

```
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("structures", ["allStructuresTree"]),
  },
created() {
      // simple actions that return axios.get API call ....
    this.$store
        .dispatch("structures/getStructureItemTree", 1223)
        .then(({ data, status }: { data: any; status: number }) => {
          debugger
          this.$store.commit("structures/setStrItemTree", data);

          // for some reason data become to be 2GB, If you know why i will appreciate your answer
        });
  },
beforeDestroy() {
    this .$store.commit("structures/setStrItemTree", []);
    this.$store._vm.$destroy();
}
```

Screenshots:

[Projects](https://ibb.co/DMtFjmQ)

[Project](https://ibb.co/smWCx1c)

[Back to Project](https://ibb.co/jwKrzz6)

VM Heap is still 2gb

[When going to project again](https://ibb.co/KzYHyyd)